# cauchy principal value in several dimension

Tags: integration

how can you aply or define the pirncipal value of a integral in more tahn one dimension ?¿ for example

PV$$ PV\iiint _{U}dx\,dy\,dz\,\frac{f(x,y,z)}{xy-x^{2}+zxy-y^{3}} $$

whose integrand in singular when $$ 0=xy-x^{2}+xyz-y^{3} $$